# Where does the callback within this express app coming from?

Tags: node.js, express

after some freecodecamp I started doing the Express js tutorial from MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page 2) for some backend.

I am stuck at understanding where the callback in the async.parallel is coming from and what is represents.

If I delete the callback the site wont load, so it must have some important meaning but unfortunately I have no glue. Is it calling the function(err, results) { res.render(‘index’, […] }) to make the result availalble for data?

```
var Book = require(’…/models/book’);
var async = require(‘async’);
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    async.parallel({   
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        [...]
        [...]
    function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Local Library Home', 
            error: err, data: results 
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking here. [Edit] the question to format the code clearly and show us what results you get, and tell us what results you expect.

Comment: I think you should read this https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced first to understand about asynchronous. The async.parallel needs some amount of time to run it and then after it has a result, it will pass the result to the callback and the callback will be called to render the page. If you remove the callback, the res.render will never call. So it won't render anything. Your client side does not receive the response, so your site will not load.

Answer (score 0):

A Callback is a generic function invoked upon the completion of an asynchronous request.
    In this particular instance, the Callback is being utilized as a method of getting the data **out** of the asynchronous request to fill the number of books on your page. These are required because these query's are non-blocking, meaning Javascript will keep executing other surrounding code until the Callback is invoked. If you want more detail on how they work in general look [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) as previously mentioned by @dnp1204. I hope this answered you question.